# Getting the auth signature in the yelp api using python

Tags: python, json, api, urllib2, yelp

I'm trying to write a simple script in python using urllib2 and json where I print the json to the console.

Currently I'm having trouble getting the auth_signature value. I already have the url variable setup with the appropriate keys except for the auth_signature. How do I go about this?

Here is what I have:

```
import json
import urllib2
import oauth2


timestamp = oauth2.generate_timestamp
nonce = oauth2.generate_nonce

url = "http://api.yelp.com/v2/search?term=food&location=Seattle&callback=callbackYelpAuth&oauth_consumer_key=XXX&oauth_consumer_secret=XXX&oauth_token=XXX&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=" + str(timestamp) + "&oauth_nonce=" + str(nonce) + "&oauth_signature=" + str(????)

json_obj = urllib2.urlopen(url)
data = json.load(json_obj)
print data
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code is working fine. Hope it will help you.

```
import urlparse


url = "http://api.yelp.com/v2/search?term=food&location=Seattle&callback=callbackYelpAuth&oauth_consumer_key=XXX&oauth_consumer_secret=XXX&oauth_token=XXX&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=temstamp_value&oauth_nonce=nonce_value&oauth_signature=signature_value"
parsed = urlparse.urlparse(url)
params = urlparse.parse_qsl(parsed.query)
for x,y in params:
    print "Parameter = "+x,", Value = "+y
```